# The requested URL /phpws/project_priyanka_3079/welcome/register was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, frameworks

i just started with code igniter and haad problem with URL tried different solutions from StackOverflow but they won't work for me
my files are as follow

welcome controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    public function register(){
        echo 'register';
    }
```

form action

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('welcome/register'); ?>">
```

base url is http://localhost/phpws/project_priyanka_3079/

tried to change .htaccess as below but it's still not working

```
RewriteEngine on

# Route home page to "locked out" special front page by uncommenting next lines
# RewriteRule ^index.htm index.html [L]
# RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]

# Send all running pages except index.php, robots.txt and the user guide to index.php

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|user_guide)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `index_page` config to false/empty (`codeigniter/application/config/config.php`) :

```php
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And change `/index.php/$1` to `index.php/$1` (`codeigniter/.htaccess`) :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```